# Script alternative of GUI command executed on login - it should not

Tags: debian, gui, mate-desktop, profile, caja

Since my main data is not in `$HOME`, I have made a small (executable) script to start the GUI file manager (`caja`) in the desired directory and put it in my local executable directory (`~/.local/bin`):

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/caja /datadir
```

To supersede the standard command `caja`, the script has the same name and the path to my local executables is listed first in my `~/.profile`:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Works fine so far, BUT whenever I log in the file manager is opened by default. No session saving is activated, no other executable from that directory is executed (tried a few `echo`-scripts and even other GUI commands).

How can I suppress this behaviour?

Using MATE as DE on Debian 10 (testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`caja` is not only a file manager, but also manages a few desktop settings, e.g. desktop symbols ([link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MATEhttps://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MATE#Prevent_Caja_from_managing_the_desktop)). Thus it will be executed when starting a MATE session. This seems unavoidable for a proper MATE session startup.

Same goes for natuilus in gnome.

---

A quick-and-dirty solution would be to name your script something else, have a script create a symlink (named `caja` and pointing to your Caja launch script) at login but after the desktop is up and running, and delete the symlink in `~/.bash_logout` (assuming your shell is bash).